# Predefining AMD module dependencies in RequireJS config

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

For the sake of loading times, I'm interested in predefining all AMD module dependencies. This is because at the moment, the module file must load before require.js can work out its dependencies. Here's an illustration to show what I mean:
[image]

Is there any way to do this with require.js? I know you can define dependencies for the shimmed modules, but can you do this for your own custom AMD modules?

Comment: Aren't you optimizing your project with r.js? It would handle bundling the dependencies into a single file, addressing the loading problem you're mentioning.

Comment: Kryger is probably right, but if you must there is the `deps` configuration ([ref](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-deps)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something you can put in the configuration you pass to RequireJS that would do what you want. There is no analogue to `shim` for modules that call `define`. However, what you *could* do is add the [`deps`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-deps) option to your configuration:

```
deps: ['module', 'dep1', 'dep2', 'dep3']
```

This will tell RequireJS to start loading immediately your module and the dependencies. You will have to maintain this list yourself but this would be true with `shim` too.

Otherwise, you can do what kryger suggested in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992318/predefining-amd-module-dependencies-in-requirejs-config/26993313#comment42516396_26992318): use [`r.js`](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) to build `module` into a single bundle that contains it and all of its dependencies. Whenever `module` is loaded, all of its dependencies are loaded at the same time. This is more efficient than using `deps` but might make things *slightly* more complicated if you ever need to load any of the dependencies by themselves. You'd have to use the runtime option [`bundles`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles) to tell RequireJS where these modules are. And just like `deps` you'd have to maintain this list yourself.

Comment: Right but what if `module` is variable depending on the URL? I suppose I could have a massive switch case to set deps...

Comment: Well, `deps` is really just sugar for putting `require(['module', 'dep1', 'dep2', 'dep3'])` immediately after your call to `require.config`. So you could forget about `deps` and have a switch that calls `require` with the appropriate set of modules.

Comment: Okay so there doesn't seem to be a perfect solution to my problem, but using require calls without a callback, or using r.js could both work.